# Blank line between each entry of List of Tables and List of Figures

Tags: tables, spacing, table-of-contents, lists

I am working on my dissertation. The requirement is: The list of figures/tables should be single spaced with a blank line between each entry. I am using the following snippet, it creates the list of figures/tables with single space but I need help on how to add blank line after each entry.

```
% Single-space list of tables, add it to the table of contents.
\def\listoftables{%
  \@restonecolfalse%
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi%
  \newpage%
  \centerline{\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\listtablename}}%
  \bigskip%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename }%
  % This group overloads \numberline to output ``Table 1.3'' instead of ``1.3''
  \begingroup%
    \let\ORIG@numberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{\ORIG@numberline{\tablename~##1:}}%
    {\ssp\@starttoc{lot}}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi%
  \endgroup %
  }
```

This is what I have now. [image: list of tables]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{uark}` from Overleaf template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-arkansas-thesis-template/gmndvzdyzjbx